# Use fprintf to memory stream

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, printf

I have a vc++ method that uses fprintf to write values to a file in the hard disc. I want to change this method so that instead of writing the values to disc, I want to return a pointer to the data.

I know in advance the size I have to allocate. Is  there any way to pass a memory stream or unsigned char pointer to fprintf?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [sprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28VS.71%29.aspx) or better yet snprintf [[_snprintf/snprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)  for VC++] (as Michael Burr pointed out and as it's noted in the Remarks section of the sprintf link).

And, since it's tagged C++, better yet use [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ability to seamlessly switch between the two, perhaps via a parameter passed in designating the target to write to, you might be better off doing your I/O using C++ streams rather than the old C printf calls.